# "In spite of" vs "other than."

Tags: sentence

I would like to know which sentence flows better. This one:

> I was a taken aback by Limei's little confession. **In spite of her
>   impulsive personality, she seemed like a normal girl, leading a normal
>   life.** Could she be more exceptional than I thought?

or this one:

> I was a taken aback by Limei's little confession. **Other than her
>   impulsive personality, she seemed like a normal girl, leading a normal
>   life.** Could she be more exceptional than I thought?

Suddenly, I'm unsure which one to use.

What I want it to say is that, *except for her impulsiveness, Limei seems like a normal person.*

Comment: They mean different things, so what do you want it to be?

Comment: @MattЭллен What I wanted to say is that, except for her impulsiveness, Limei seemed like a normal person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering what you want to say, ***other than*** is perfect. You can also say, "***Besides*** her impulsive personality.."

***In spite of her impulsive personality*** means she hardly behaves as a normal girl, which has taken you aback. Whereas, ***Other than her impulsive personality*** means she is usually both impulsive and humble in her way of living.

Answer (score 1):

"Other than ..." means "except for ..." - and is far less 'harsh' or 'condemning'.

If wanting "in spite of", I would actually use "*Despite* her impulsive personality", but both of these options implies that her impulsiveness is a **major** character defect.